Recurring contributions webhook error causing payments and memberships to be marked as pending (Stripe payment processor)
When each memberships is created, the membership and the recurring membership are being marked as pending. After some digging, I've found that the problem is caused by a payment processor webhook failing. When I retry the webhook (via https://example.com/civicrm/a#/paymentprocessorWebhook), it succeeds and resolves the problem.
Is there a way I can resolve this error to avoid having to manually retry webhooks for every membership?
Edit: the specific webhook error that is coming up is doInvoicePaymentFailed: Contribution not found
